# Linux - What resources require raised privileges C/C++ programming?

Tags: c++, linux, debian, privileges, setuid

I am in the process of developing a daemon and user application which will talk to the daemon over a UNIX domain socket to send commands, get status information, etc. The user application will be run by non-root users with the setuid bit set so that it will have an effective uid of root, which will allow it to access resources requiring root privileges. Most files, sockets, devices (ttys, etc.) require root privileges to access them through the file, ioctl system calls. I do not want to run with raised privileges all the time during runtime since it is not secure and frowned upon.

My question, since I have not been able to find anything in books or on the Internet, is there a comprehensive list of system calls, resources that need root privileges to access? I know the resources I am using need raised privileges since I can verify that by debugging with/without the setuid bit set for a given executable, but I am just curious if there is a compiled list somewhere outlining when, when you do not need raised privileges to access resources?

Comment: Almost certainly not... imagine, it would need to be updated every time *anyone* added a new privileged operation (which is something anyone could do, even you).

Comment: Perhaps the first step would be go look at the Linux-specific POSIX function documentation?

Comment: Good point on the being able to add a privileged operation, I guess I was more thinking standard system calls, nothing custom added or being denied by custom server applications, etc that might deny. I am by no means an expert so I did not think of all the possibilites. I have dug into the man pages and there are numerous calls where EACCES  is a possibility but I was not sure if there was some kind of compiled list. Thanks for the responses, I will do some more man page reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ioctl` does not require raised privileges *per se*. A given device might be restricted to special priviliges, but that doesn't mean your program needs to be run as `root`:

On traditional linux system, privilege authorization is handled via *file-permissions* (mostly: *group memberships*).

Consider accessing a webcam, which shows up as `/dev/video3`

$ ls -l /dev/video3
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Dec  2 09:21 /dev/video3

So this device can be read/write by `root` *and* any user belonging to the `video` group.

So it is enough if the user of a program that wants to control `/dev/video3` is a member of the `video` group.

Note: "user" need not be a human user; it can also be a *system user* who's sole purpose is to run a given daemon.

If this is too coarse (e.g. you want to grant a given user access to `/dev/video3` but *not* `/dev/video0`; but by default both are writeable by the `video` group), it is easy enough to setup `udev` rules that will grant more specific permissions for individual devices.

Comment: That is what I have been reading up on since posting this, and Linux capabilities. I do not fully understand the udev part but I am looking into it. One thing I do not want is a user who is in the tty or dialup group be able to echo > garbage out of one of the interfaces to cause havoc. This is an embedded device that I would like users to be able to log in, monitor status, maybe update config locally, but not be able to trash the system on purpose or accidently.